# Connecting to SQL Server with PDO_MSSQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a problem while trying to connect to my SQL Server 2000 database using pdo_mssql with this line:

```
$connection = new PDO ('mssql:host=localhost;dbname=DNAME', 'user', 'password');
```

The exception is the following:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server. (severity 5)' in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\public\test.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\public\test.php(2): PDO->__construct('mssql:host=loca...', 'user', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\public\test.php on line 2
```

If I make the connection using the function mssql_connect() as follows, I obtain no error and my connection is correctly made:

```
$link = mssql_connect ('localhost', 'user', 'password');
```

Any idea? Where can I read the detailed error message? Thanks

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.2.17 with pdo_mssql and mssql extensions installed

Comment: Does your database name contain any non-alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My database name had the character "-", removing it solved the problem!

Comment: Same problem here... but cannot remove "-" from database name.
Tried connection on another DB and works very well.