# PHP, MSSQL, SQL SERVER, WAMP, PDO, Windows Authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo, wamp

I have searched the site and the web for a PROPER tutorial on how to connect from your WAMP PHP to a local SQL SERVER without success.

Articles I have found on this site are:

- [PHP to SQL Server without ODBC or MSSQL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643988/php-to-sql-server-without-odbc-or-mssql-support)
- [Connecting to SQL Server with PDO_MSSQL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650598/connecting-to-sql-server-with-pdo-mssql-in-php)
- [Error connecting to SQL server with MSSQL and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031334/error-connecting-to-sql-server-with-mssql-and-php)
- [MSSQL error (saying not enabled when it is) using WAMP / PHP 5.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356178/mssql-error-saying-not-enabled-when-it-is-using-wamp-php-5-3-4)
- [Connecting to MSSQL server 2008 with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099586/connecting-to-mssql-server-2008-with-php)
- [PHP error connecting to MS SQL database using PDO_DBLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101719/php-error-connecting-to-ms-sql-database-using-pdo-dblib)

None of them really help me.

Can someone post a proper article on how to connect from WAMP PHP to a local SQL Server with Windows Authentication. Also if possible with SQL server authentication.

I have tried installing `php_pdo_mssql`, `php_mssql`, extensions but I am getting unable to connect to server errors. I can connect to the server through SQL Server management studio when I just type Database name: DEV-13 and put Windows Authentication as login credentials.

A tutorial to for installing PHP extensions and connecting to sql server for dummies would be perfect!

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide from Microsoft. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296205%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to connect using the identity that Apache is running as, or a different user?  If the same user as Apache, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx .  Am looking for another article now as to how to use arbitrary credentials.

Also, mssql_* is in my mind deprecated.  It's a pain to find the right DLLs for it, and it's not very well supported (though one of the only options on Linux).

I suggest using sqlsrv through PDO.  That way you get the benefits of the newest (Microsoft supported) connection method, and worst case if you have to change back to mssql_* drivers, you can just change the PDO connection string and be done (no query changes or anything).

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out and get back to your post and the identity doesn't matter in my case I guess. Though I will deploy this website to a different machine eventually.

Comment: I've looked around quite a bit, and as I can tell, there's no way to do Windows Authentication through the native client (the PHP hook-in anyway) other than the user Apache is running as.  I haven't used the mssql_* extension in probably 5 years, so I don't know if it's the same case with that.  If I were you, I'd be tempted to just use SQL Server authentication.  Though I suppose if mssql_* does support it, you could use it.  You could still use PDO, and then if you ever  ran into problems, you could switch to sqlsrv worst case.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to get it to work with PDO for sure. Surprised PHP didn't provide a data access layer before. I think PDO just came with PHP 5?

Comment: It is indeed PHP >= 5.0.  PHP < 5.0 was a horrid little language with horrible performance and OOP support.  PDO requires certain OOP features that weren't existent or performant enough in PHP 4 :).

Comment: If you mean an ORM, that would be quite difficult.  A uniform connection/querying interface that is procedural already exists through in odbc_*.  It's not DB agnostic as most ORM or DBALs are though because it still deals with raw SQL.  :)

Answer (score 0):

this one: http://www.davidlauzon.net/2009/02/ms-sql-server-2008-with-php/ ?